# bash what is the test attribute for hidden directories and files

Tags: linux, bash, shell

In bash script, to test if a directory entry is a folder, we use -d ,

```
shopt -s dotglob nullglob # to include hidden fille
for entry in *
if [ -d "$entry" ]; then # regular directory, not hidden ones...
```

To test for file, -f

```
if [ -f "$entry" ]; then # regular file, not hidden ones...
```

What attribute for hidden directory? ,  and hidden file?

Comment: This can be useful https://askubuntu.com/questions/468901/how-to-show-only-hidden-files-in-terminal

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Hidden files / directories exist only by name convention in UNIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden_file_and_hidden_directory#Unix_and_Unix-like_environments). Their names start with a dot:

```
if [[ -d "${entry}" && "${entry}" =~ ^\. ]] ; then
    echo "${entry} is a hidden folder"
fi
```

Further (interesting) read: https://plus.google.com/u/0/+RobPikeTheHuman/posts/R58WgWwN9jp

Comment: OK. But when executed, I got errors like "conditional binary operator expected" and syntax error near `~='. Can you point me where i am wrong? Thanks

Comment: @Mahouk: Make sure you're using `bash`

Comment: @Mahouk Yeah, run the script with `/bin/bash`, not `/bin/sh`

Comment: I see, =~ instead of ~=. However, I does not work because hidden directories do not match `[[ -d "${entry}" ]]`. Anyway thank you for your reply @hek2mgl

Comment: They should match. A *hidden* directory is still a directory. About `=~`, my bad! sorry.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a way to list *hidden* directories in the current directory using **glob**:

```
shopt -s dotglob nullglob

for entry in */; do
    [[ $entry = .* ]] && echo "$entry"
done
```

- Glob `*/` finds all directories in current current directory
- Glob `.*` matches all directory names that start with a dot